# Improving DB Efficiency for Attribute / Value Table

Tags: sql, postgresql, database-design, entity-attribute-value

Each month, I process approximately 5M credit reports with each report containing roughly 1600 attributes, ranging in size from `smallint` to `Varchar(1000)`.

These credit report attributes vary from credit provider to credit provider.

I'm looking for any advice on how to better improve the schema below that captures the credit data:

```
credit_reports
 - id (int, PK)
 - credit_report_provider_id (int, FK)

credit_report_attributes
 - id (int, PK)
 - credit_report_id (int)
 - attribute (varchar(10))
 - value (varchar(1000))

credit_report_providers
 - id (int, PK)
 - name (varchar(15))
```

My chief concern is the use of [Entity-Value-Attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Entity-Value-Attributes) design in the `credit_report_attributes` table.

Several hundred of the attributes are `tinyints`, but because this table needs to be generic enough to support any number of attributes and value types/lengths, I'm worried it will cause performance issues as this table rapidly grows.

Is there an alternative approach that will allow me to more efficiently capture the credit report attributes from a number of different credit report providers?

Comment: what kind of queries you do against the attributes and values?

Comment: A `hstore` column (in the `credit_reports` table) is a very efficient alternative to EAV

Comment: I've considered this, but was concerned about lack of strictly enforced schema. For example, if we want to do retroactive analysis on all credit_reports from provider X, we won't have any assurance that all of those credit reports have the same set of attributes and values, right? (unless enforced on the application / code side)

Comment: You do not have that guarantee with the EAV model either

Answer (score 0):

An alternate approach would be to have an attribute type column in an attributes table and then split your tiny int attributes to one table and your more string based attributes to another table.  But this would depend on how you're doing your queries and your indexing model.

For example:

```
credit_reports
 - id (int, PK)
 - credit_report_provider_id (int, FK)

credit_report_attributes_int
 - id (int, PK)
 - credit_report_id (int)
 - attribute (varchar(10))
 - value (tinyint)

credit_report_attributes_string
 - id (int, PK)
 - credit_report_id (int)
 - attribute (varchar(10))
 - value (varchar(1000))

credit_report_providers
 - id (int, PK)
 - name (varchar(15))

credit_report_providers_attributes
 - credit_report_provider_id (int, FK)
 - typeid (int, PK)
 - name (varchar(15))
```